# MongoDB find date range if overlap with other dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have many documents with the schema shown below each containing (start date, enddate) as shown in the schema below. Is there a simple way to know before saving a new document if the new document startdate, enddate will overlap with previously saved documents startdate, enddate? Thanks

```
{
    "title" : "",
    "owner" : "",
    "notes" : "",
    "startdate" : "",
    "enddate" : ""
}
```

Below is the only document currently saved:

```
Document.(anonymous function) {_id: "FADnPAxRu4Ps5hkLz", 
   title: "Round A", 
   customerid: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr", 
   startdate: "11/21/2014 7:25 AM"…}
_id: "FADnPAxRu4Ps5hkLz"customerid: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr"
enddate: "11/30/2014 6:09 AM"
startdate: "11/21/2014 7:25 AM"
title: "Round A"__proto__: Document.(anonymous function)
```

When I try executing any of the following query on the above document it return nothing, even though there is an obvious overlap here.

```
db.Projects.find({'startdate': {$lt: '11/25/2014 6:26 PM'}, 'enddate': {$gt: '11/19/2014 6:26 PM'}}, {sort:{time: -1}});

db.Projects.find({'startdate': {$lt: '11/30/2014 6:26 PM'}, 'enddate': {$gt: '11/21/2014 6:26 PM'}}, {sort:{time: -1}});
```

Comment: Your "dates" are strings and are not lexically ordered. Convert these to a proper [Date type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The time overlap can be illustrated with these 4 cases in the figure below, where S/E is startdate/enddate of the new document and S'/E' is startdate/enddate of any existing document:

```
  S'                  E' 
  |-------------------|

   S                E 
   |****************|

S'          E' 
|-----------|

      S'          E' 
      |-----------|

              S'          E' 
              |-----------|
```

In 4 cases we have `S'<E` and `E'>S`. The query to find all documents with overlapped time can be:

```
db.collection.find({"startdate": {"$lt": E}, "enddate": {"$gt": S}})
```

EDIT:

Your startdate and enddate are in string format, and not lexically ordered, hence can't use "$gt" and "$lt" for comparison. You should convert them to Date type:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(
  function (e) {
    // convert date if it is a string
    if (typeof e.startdate === 'string') {
       e.startdate = new Date(e.startdate);
    }
    if (typeof e.enddate === 'string') {
       e.enddate = new Date(e.enddate);
    } 
    // save the updated document
    db.collection.save(e);
  }
)
```

The final query will be:

```
db.collection.find({"startdate": {"$lt": new Date("E")}, "enddate": {"$gt": new Date("S")}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am not getting any results from executing the above query, despite the date being overlapped or not I am always getting LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: Minimongo.Sorter, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: Minimongo.Matcher, skip: undefined…} ...any clue what I could be missing, doing wrong here? Thanks again

Comment: @MChan, Post your query and some of your data so we can find out what is your issue.

Comment: I updated the question with the only document I have saved and the queries I am trying to execute

Comment: I see the issue. You are using a string type instead of date type in "startdate" and "enddate". You should use Mongo ISODate instead. And where is the 'time' field in sort()? It is not in your document.

Comment: The time is a mistake which I copied from another query in my program where I have time field. Regarding startdate, end date how I can set the field to be date if I am taking the date from form field, posting it to db without having a pre-defined schema? Thanks

Comment: @Mchan I update anwer with solution to convert your date string

Comment: is it possible to have a validator that prevents inserting documents with overlapping dates?

Comment: @BalázsNémeth, I don't think validator supports this date overlapping checking. You need to implement it in application level

Comment: @anhlc I was afraid to hear this because then how do I prevent race condition between multiple instances?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of the accepted answer, I was able to fuse together all four cases and came up with a perfect solution. Hope it might help others.

```
     S                E 
     |****************|
  S1                     E1
  |----------------------|
       S2        E2
       |----------|
 S3          E3
 |-----------|
              S4           E4
              |-------------|
```

Case 1: The interval completely covers the start date and end date

```
{ "startDate": { $lte: moment(S1).toDate() } }
{ "endDate": { $gte: moment(E1).toDate() } }
```

Case 2: The interval is completely inside the start date and end date

```
{ "startDate": { $gte: moment(S2).toDate() } }
{ "endDate": { $lte: moment(E2).toDate() } }
```

Case 3: The start date is outside the interval and the end date is inside the interval

```
{ "endDate": { $gte: moment(S3).toDate() } }
{ "endDate": { $lte: moment(E3).toDate() } }
```

Case 4: The start date is inside the interval and the end date is outside the interval

```
{ "startDate": { $gte: moment(S4).toDate() } }
{ "startDate": { $lte: moment(E4).toDate() } }
```

Combining all four cases with '$and' and '$or' to get the data where at least one case is met.

```
const query = {};
const datePipeArray = [];
datePipeArray.push({ "$and":[
    { "startDate": { $gte: moment(queryStartDate).toDate() } },
    { "endDate": { $lte: moment(queryEndDate).toDate() } }
]});
datePipeArray.push({ "$and":[
    { "endDate": { $gte: moment(queryStartDate).toDate() } },
    { "endDate": { $lte: moment(queryEndDate).toDate() } }
]});
datePipeArray.push({ "$and":[
    { "startDate": { $gte: moment(queryStartDate).toDate() } },
    { "startDate": { $lte: moment(queryEndDate).toDate() } }
]});
datePipeArray.push({ "$and":[
    { "startDate": { $lte: moment(queryStartDate).toDate() } },
    { "endDate": { $gte: moment(queryEndDate).toDate() } }
]});
query["$or"] = datePipeArray;
db.calendar.find(query)
```

> P.S: moment is optional

Comment: why split these up in 4 cases? The accepted answer shows that in all 4 cases the condition is the same:  `S'<E` and `E'>S`. So, it can be handled with the 1 query shown.