# Find length in seconds that date ranges overlap

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assume I have a document that has start / end times of a particular event. Using MongoDB I want to determine the overlap (in seconds) given another start / end time.

For example I have the following existing document:

```
startTime:2018-02-06 12:36:33.000
endTime: 2018-02-06 12:59:04.000
```

Then given I want to compare it to the start time `2018-02-06 12:58:04.000` and end time `2018-02-06 15:59:04.000`. I would expect my `totalOverlapInSeconds` to be `60`.

There are many examples on how to determine if the dates overlap ([MongoDB find date range if overlap with other dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876803/mongodb-find-date-range-if-overlap-with-other-dates)). But how do you get the seconds in which they overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the difference you can [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html) [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) `end` values and [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html) `start` values from both sets. If two sets don't overlap each other then you'll get negative value so you can use [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html) once again to assign `0` in such case. Try:

```
let startTimeParam = ISODate("2018-02-06 12:58:04.000");
let endTimeParam = ISODate("2018-02-06 15:59:04.000");

db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            seconds: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        totalMs: {
                            $max: [
                                0,
                                { $subtract: [ { "$min": [ "$endTime", endTimeParam ] }, { $max: [ "$startTime", startTimeParam ] } ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $divide: [ "$$totalMs", 1000 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable and [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) to convert ms to seconds.

[MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-eLhJDIJhxt)

Below diagram illustrates all the possible cases on two sets. **r** represents the point in time which will be taken as a right side of subtraction while **l** represents the left side of subtraction:

[image]